# AngularJS preload pages (off line mode)

Tags: angularjs

I would like to preload templates in AngularJS (with ng-route) so that when I am on the home page, after loading all the necessaries element, I can download some sub-pages of my application in order to, if the user lost connexion, he is still able to go on that page, without an internet connexion.

I tried to make different asynchronous calls on my pages but I'm not getting anywhere.

I hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for this:

The first one is to use an Ajax call and get the HTML for your Sites and load it into the template Cache by yourself:

```
$http.get('./template.en.html').then(function (result) { 
    //put template into cache
    $templateCache.put('myTemplateName', result.data);
});
```

The second would be to use OcLazyLoad:

```
$ocLazyLoad.load([
  'path/to/template.html'
]);
```

But with this approach your Template files need to look like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplateName">
  Content of the template.
</script>
```

Also you could load your controller files with ocLazyLoad

Comment: Thanks I will try this solution